# Tomcat couldn't serve from a servlet bootstrapped by spring java configuration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlets

This `Spring` [example](https://github.com/svinniks/learning-spring/tree/main/example-05-dispatcher-servlet-code-configuration-2) uses a `Java` configuration to register a servlet. To test this,

1. add a latest `maven-war-plugin` to ignore missing `web.xml`, and

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

2. build a war, and
3. create a `Dockerfile` to use `Tomcat`, and

```
FROM tomcat

COPY example-05-dispatcher-servlet-code-configuration-2-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
```

4. build and run a container, and

```
docker build .
docker run -p 8080:8080 -it <image>
```

5. send a request to `/hello`.

```
curl -4 -v -XGET http://localhost:8080/hello
```

However, the tomcat didn't find the controller, and this was what I got:

```
The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

What did I wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Tomcat didn't find the servlet context (application), because its prefix is `/example-05-dispatcher-servlet-code-configuration-2-1.0-SNAPSHOT/`, not `/`. Copy the file as `ROOT.war` to deploy your application at the root of your server.

Comment: Basically `tomcat` refers to Tomcat 10 from some time now. Use the `tomcat:9` tag instead.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz It did work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you miss the context path of the app which is the name of the folder inside `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/` that containing the exploded WAR . So in your case , please try :

```sh
curl -4 -v -XGET http://localhost:8080/example-05-dispatcher-servlet-code-configuration-2-1.0-SNAPSHOT/hello
```

If you really want to access by `http://localhost:8080/hello` , you have to deploy the WAR to `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/`.  As the tomcat docker images already has a welcome page app deployed to this context , you need to delete this app first and rename your WAR to `ROOT.war` , something like :

```
FROM tomcat
RUN rm -rvf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
COPY example-05-dispatcher-servlet-code-configuration-2-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
```

Comment: Thanks for your time! Unfortunately, `curl -4 -v -XGET http://localhost:8080/example-05-dispatcher-servlet-code-configuration-2-1.0-SNAPSHOT/hello` also gives me `404 NOT FOUND`. This is driving me crazy, haha.